# How to compare large string integer values

Tags: c#, string, int

Currently I am working on a program that processes extremely large `integer`numbers .

To prevent hitting the `intiger.maxvalue` a script that processes strings as numbers, and splits them up into a `List<int>`as following

0 is the highest currently known value

- list entry 0: 123 (hundred twenty three million)
- list entry 1: 321 (three hundred twenty one thousand)
- list entry 2: 777 (seven hundred seventy seven)

Now my question is: How would one check if the incoming string value is sub tractable from these values?

The start for subtraction I currently made is as following, but I am getting stuck on the subtracting part.

```
public bool Subtract(string value)
{
    string cleanedNumeric = NumericAndSpaces(value);
    List<string> input = new List<string>(cleanedNumeric.Split(' '));

    // In case 1) the amount is bigger 2) biggest value exceeded by a 10 fold 
    // 3)  biggest value exceeds the value
    if (input.Count > values.Count ||
        input[input.Count - 1].Length > values[0].ToString().Length ||
        FastParseInt(input[input.Count -1]) > values[0])
        return false;

    // Flip the array for ease of comparison
    input.Reverse();

    return true;
}
```

**EDIT**
Current target for the highest achievable number in this program is a [Googolplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googolplex) And are limited to .net3.5 MONO

Comment: I am not sure what you try to achieve, but have you already looked into using  [System.Numerics.BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx)?

Comment: Why not use a `long`, which should probably be big enough?

Comment: @elgonzo yes, but I believe this is also a limited value up to  2^(2^33) if i believe correctly.

Comment: @MXD, no. It has no upper and lower bounds - the limits are simply given by the available memory. Read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx). Especially the remarks section... (reading the remarks section should always be one of the first steps to validate one's assumptions ;-)  )

Comment: @MXD There is no limit other than memory from what I know... Its description is *Represents an arbitrarily large signed integer.*

Comment: @elgonzo so the limit, set at 2gb making the limit 2^(2^33) if the sign bit is stored separately, otherwise only 2^(2^32)

Comment: @MXD, why 2GB limit? My machine has 32GB RAM. If you take away 4GB you would still have 28GB left. Workstations could even have 128GB RAM or more. Not sure whether this would be sufficient for a Googolplex. (I would need brain for that to think about ;-) )

Comment: @MXD, i had a quick look at the source code of BigInteger. Darn, you are right. It uses an uint[] array internally to store the bits of the number. Bummer...

Comment: @elgonzo seems that I cant use big ints anyway, because I am limited to MONO .net3.5 ;)

Comment: @MXD, if you need more precision, perhaps you could borrow from the [implementation of BigInteger](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Numerics/System/Numerics/BigInteger.cs,035eb7acfa6585a0) and roll your own implementation using a linked list of multiple arrays or such instead of a meager single array. Just a thought...

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean "subtractable"?  Is the incoming value to the list less than the previous values?

Comment: @ChrisSchubert Thats what I am crashing on, Say you have 100,000. And wish to subtract 100,001. How do I verify that the given amount can be deduced, when the storing format as before mentioned is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do some testing on this because I haven't run extensive tests but it has worked on the cases I've put it through.  Also, it might be worth ensuring that each character in the string is truly a valid integer as this procedure would bomb given a non-integer character.  Finally, it expects positive numbers for both subtrahend and minuend.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // In subtraction, a subtrahend is subtracted from a minuend to find a difference.
        string minuend = "900000";
        string subtrahend = "900001";

        var isSubtractable = IsSubtractable(subtrahend, minuend);
    }

    public static bool IsSubtractable(string subtrahend, string minuend)
    {
        minuend = minuend.Trim();
        subtrahend = subtrahend.Trim();

        // maybe loop through characters and ensure all are valid integers

        // check if the original number is longer - clearly subtractable
        if (minuend.Length > subtrahend.Length) return true;
        // check if original number is shorter - not subtractable
        if (minuend.Length < subtrahend.Length) return false;

        // at this point we know the strings are the same length, so we'll
        // loop through the characters, one by one, from the start, to determine
        // if the minued has a higher value character in a column of the number.
        int numberIndex = 0;

        while (numberIndex < minuend.Length )
        {
            Int16 minuendCharValue = Convert.ToInt16(minuend[numberIndex]);
            Int16 subtrahendCharValue = Convert.ToInt16(subtrahend[numberIndex]);

            if (minuendCharValue > subtrahendCharValue) return true;
            if (minuendCharValue < subtrahendCharValue) return false;

            numberIndex++;
        }

        // number are the same
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Already checking for a valid integer, but thanks for the note ;). But given the scenario stated above, where we go into extremly huge numbers. Wouldn't the `Convert.ToInt16` go out of bounds? Hence the reason I split the numbers and store them in units of 3 in a list instead.

Comment: @MXD Actually, after we've determined the lengths of the numbers are the same, we loop through each character one by one checking if the minued has a higher value in a certain column than the subtrahend.  For example, in `minued = 50030000` and `subtrahend = 50020000`, once we check that 4th number column we'll recognize the minued is larger, and thus the two are 'subtractable'.  So we're never storing a number greater than 9 in the `Int16`.

Comment: Yes, I most certainly have. So far it has been going pretty well, all tough every once in a while it returns as able to subtract whilst it could not subtract, once I figure out where thats coming from I am willing to accept this answer ;)

Comment: @MXD if you give me an example of a set that fails I can adjust the procedure

Answer (score 1):

**[BigInteger]**(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) is of aribtary size.

Run this code if you don't believe me

```
        var foo = new BigInteger(2);


        while (true)
        {
            foo = foo * foo;
        }
```

Things get crazy. My debugger (VS2013) becomes unable to represent the number before it's done. ran it for a short time and got a number with 1.2 million digits in base 10 from ToString. It is big enough. There is a 2GB limit on object, which can be overriden in .NET 4.5 with the setting gcAllowVeryLargeObjects

**Now what to do if you are using .NET 3.5?** You basically need to reimplement BigInteger (obviously only taking what you need, there is a lot in there).

```
public class MyBigInteger
{
     uint[] _bits; // you need somewhere to store the value to an arbitrary length.
```

....

You also need to perform maths on these arrays. here is the Equals method from BigInteger:

```
 public bool Equals(BigInteger other)
    {
        AssertValid();
        other.AssertValid();

        if (_sign != other._sign)
            return false;
        if (_bits == other._bits) 
            // _sign == other._sign && _bits == null && other._bits == null
            return true;

        if (_bits == null || other._bits == null)
            return false;
        int cu = Length(_bits);
        if (cu != Length(other._bits))
            return false;
        int cuDiff = GetDiffLength(_bits, other._bits, cu);
        return cuDiff == 0;
    }
```

It basically does cheap length and sign comparisons of the byte arrays, then, if that doesn't produce a difference hands off to GetDiffLength.

```
    internal static int GetDiffLength(uint[] rgu1, uint[] rgu2, int cu)
    {
        for (int iv = cu; --iv >= 0; )
        {
            if (rgu1[iv] != rgu2[iv])
                return iv + 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Which does the expensive check of looping through the arrays looking for a difference.

All you math will have to follow this pattern and can largely be ripped of from the [.Net source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Numerics/System/Numerics/BigInteger.cs).

**Googleplex and 2GB:**

Here the 2GB limit becomes a problem, because you will be needing an object size of [3.867×10^90 gigabyte](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42764/how-to-calculate-the-disk-space-required-to-store-googolplex). This the the point where you give up, or get clever and store objects as powers at the cost of not being able to represent a lot of them. *2

if you moderate your expectations, it doesn't actually change the maths of BigInteger to split _bits into multiple jagged arrays *1. You change the cheap checks a bit. Rather than checking the size of the array, you check the number of subarrays and then the size of the last one. Then the loop needs to be a bit more (but not much) more complex in that it does elementwise array comparison for each sub array. There are other changes as well, but it's by no means impossible and gets you out of the 2GB limit.

*1 Note use jagged arrays[][], not multidimensional arrays [,] which are still subject to the same limit.

*2 Ie give up on precision and store the mantissa and exponent. If you look how floating point numbers are implemented they can't represent all numbers between their max and min (as the number of real numbers in a range is 'bigger' than infinite). They make a complex trade off between precision and range. If you are wanting to do this, looking at float implementations will be a lot more useful than taking about integer representations like Biginteger.

Comment: I am definitely going to try this out thanks allot for this ;)